# Can't create a Production certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

I am an admin in an Apple Developer Program (organization).
I want to create a Distribution Provisionning Profile to upload my own app on iTunes Connect.
I read that I need to create a Production Certificate before.

In Member Center, "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles", I tried to create it.
But, I can't because I can only check "iOS App Development":

[image]

As I read, I have normally to check "In-House and Ad Hoc" to create a Production Certificate. Why I don't see it ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps you:

You should have " Intermediate Certificate Authorities " in you key chain access as shown below:

[image]

To use your certificates, the correct intermediate certificate needs to be in your keychain. An intermediate certificate ensures that your certificates were issued by a trusted source. The intermediate certificate, named Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority, is installed in your system keychain when you install Xcode. The intermediate certificate for Developer ID certificates is called Developer ID Certification Authority. If you accidentally remove an intermediate certificate, you can install it again.

First try refreshing your provisioning profiles in Xcode, as described in Refreshing Provisioning Profiles in Xcode, to install missing intermediate certificates. If that doesn’t work for you, download and install the missing intermediate certificate.

**To install a missing intermediate certificate**

1. Go to http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority.
2. Click “Download certificate” under Apple Intermediate Certificates for the intermediate certificate you’re missing.

[image]

A certificate file, with a .cer extension, appears in your Downloads folder.

3. Double-click the certificate file to install it in your system keychain.

Answer (score 0):

Please mind that the last WWDR cert [expired on Feb 16, 2016](http://appleinsider.com/articles/16/02/15/some-developers-caught-unprepared-for-apple-wwdr-certificate-update).

So you might have not actually lost your WWDR cert, but rather it expired.